# How to understand if a transfer is an ingoing or an outgoing one by calling getAccountData?

Tags: iri-node, transaction, iri-legacy-api

I'd like to know how I can check if a transfer is an ingoing or an outgoing one, and know the respective sent/received amount by calling `getAccountData` from the Iota JavaScript library.

Comment: i solved by reading this [link](https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/bundles.html)

Comment: Please provide a proper answer then which includes the important bits of what you linked.